# How to use openssl_decrypt() insted of mcrypt_decrypt()

Tags: php

I have a string which is perfectly decrypted using:

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
```

Now, I have to decrypt data using the `openssl_decrypt()` function.

I tried using:

```
openssl_decrypt ($encrypted, 'AES-256-CBC', $key , 0 , $iv);
```

But, I got:

```
RESULT = <blank>
```

Comment: Well, the first issue is that you wont be able to decrypt old data with the newer code (especially when the old encrypt is using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`). You will have to first decrypt it the old way, then re-encrypt it with `openssl_encrypt`. Then using `openssl_decrypt` will work.

Comment: It donot allow me to decrypt using mcrypt_decrypt and gives error decrepted   method

Comment: Then your question is unclear, because right in your first sentence you say "*is perfectly decrypted using mcrypt_decrypt*"... So which is it?

Comment: When i was using it in the previous versions of php it was working fine but in current version on linux it is giving me the error

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message, and some information about your project setup? Did something change in recent time?

Comment: I'm going to guess that your PHP upgraded to 7 which removed the ability to use mcrypt. And now you are a bit stuck between a rock and a hard place with the prior encrypted data (possibly in a database?). This may prove to be a very tricky situation if you cannot get your data back onto php5 so you can decrypt/re-encrypt new :(

Comment: While expecting the openssl version of AES to be compatible with the mcrypt version of Rijndael is optimistic but worth a try, there is no way that you can decrypt using a different block size than you encrypted with.

Comment: (BTW even if you use the same block size, it won't work - mcrypt uses the key as-is but openssl applies a KDF to the key)

Comment: Is there any other encryption technique that will help to decrypt data